# Invalid statement / prepare while doing SELECT on class

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, prepared-statement

What's wrong with this class?

```
<?php
class myClass {
  private $dbServer  = 'localhost';
  private $dbUser    = 'db_name';
  private $dbPass    = 'db_pass';
  private $dbName    = 'db_name';

  var $error  = NULL;
  var $db;

  function connect()
  {
    // improved by http://stackoverflow.com/users/618622/bv202
    try
    {
      $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbServer . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
      $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      return (!$this->db) ? FALSE : TRUE;
      $this->db = NULL;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
      print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
      die();
    }
  }

  function columns($table)
  {
    if(!$this->connect()) $this->error =  'Error connecting/creating PDO.';
    else
    {
      $columnsTable = $this->db->prepare("DESCRIBE :_table"); // here points out the error
      if(!$columnsTable) $this->error = 'Invalid statement';
      else
      {
        $columnsTable->bindParam(':_table', $table);
        if(!$columnsTable->execute()) $this->error = 'Error while executing statement.';
        else
        {
          $columns = $columnsTable->fetchAll();
          if(!$columns) $this->error = 'Invalid fetch.';
          else
          {
            $columnsTable->closeCursor();
            foreach($columns as $column=>$columnData)
            {
              $results[] = $columnData['COLUMN_NAME'];
            }
          }
        }
        $columnsTable = NULL;
      }
    }
    return !empty($this->error) ? $this->error : $results;
  }

}

$control = new myClass;
$content = $control->columns('customers');
var_dump($content);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
string(17) "Invalid statement"
```

I tested the SQL directly on MySQL without errors.

MySQL version: 5.0.92
PHP version: 5.2.11

Comment: You should always catch exceptions when creating the PDO object. If you don't do this and something goes wrong (like the mysql server is down), your database info (including passwords!) may be outputted. See: http://be2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: @Bv202 improved the connection function, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Prepared statements, you cannot use parameters just anywhere in any possible kind of query : it's not like a "put this into a string" : prepared statements depend on the server.

I suppose MySQL doesn't accept a parameter in a `describe` query -- which explains the error.

You'll have to not use prepared statements, for this kind of query.

Quoting [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html) :

> Parameter markers can be used only
>   **where data values should appear**, not
>   for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so
>   forth.

In your case, you are trying to use a parameter marker for an identifier *(a table's name)* -- which is not supported.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Pascal, I changed the line and now it works: `$columnsTable = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = :_table");`